# Generating seed data with relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I want to generate seed data for some books and each book will have a rating per user. I am not getting the desired result when I run my `db:seed` for the factory and seeder

**Book Factory**

```
use App\Book;
use App\Rating;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Book::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    'title'     => $faker->sentence,
    'author'    => $faker->name,
    'user_id'   => 1
];
});

$factory->define(Rating::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    'user_id'   => 1,
    'book_id'   => mt_rand(1, 5),
    'rating'   => mt_rand(1, 5)
];
});
```

**BooksTableSeeder**

```
public function run()
{
    // First remove existing books records
    Book::truncate();

    factory(App\Book::class, 5)->create()->each(function ($book) {
        // Add book rating
        $ratings = factory(App\Rating::class, 1)->make();
        $book->ratings()->saveMany($ratings);
    });
}
```

**Wrong behaviour** This code returns a book with multiple ratings from one user

**Right behaviour** A book should only have one rating per user

How can I correct my code to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the book_id when generating the ratings:

```
    factory(App\Book::class, 5)->create()->each(function ($book) {
    // Add book rating
    $ratings = factory(App\Rating::class, 1)->create(['book_id' => $book->id]);
    $book->ratings()->saveMany($ratings);
});
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. I need to play some more with seed data to fully grasp the concept though.

Comment: You are welcome, basically this way you "force" the factory to generate the rating with the specified book_id.